# A request to send or recieve data was disallowed (UDP file-trasnfer)

Tags: sockets, python-3.x, udp, file-transfer

I am trying to make a simple file server. The problem with my code is when the user inputs a file name on client and send to server the server should response as 'EXISTS' or 'NOT EXISTS' back to client. I inserted a print command on server side that if the file requested by client exists print exists and that is working fine but server is not able to send the response back to client so that client can then download the file. Below are my Client and Server code aswell as Traceback error at server side. Please help I'm new to python.

**Server.py**

```
import socket
import threading
import os

def retrvfile(name, sock):
    filename = sock.recv(1024)
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        print("exists")
        sock.send("EXISTS".encode())
        userresponse = s.recv(1024)
        if userresponse[:2] == 'OK':
                with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
                        bytestosend = f.read(1024)
                        sock.send(bytestosend)
                        while bytestosend != "":
                                bytestosend = f.read(1024)
                                sock.send(bytestosend)

    else:
            print("do not exists")
            sock.send("error".encode())

    sock.close()

def main():
    HOST = '127.0.0.1'
    PORT = 9090

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    print ("listening")
    print ("server started")
    while True:
            t = threading.Thread(target=retrvfile, args=("retrThread", s))
            t.start()
s.close    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Client.p**

```
import socket
import sys
def main():
            HOST = '127.0.0.1'
            PORT = 9090

            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
            s.connect((HOST, PORT))

            print ("UDP target IP:", HOST)
            print ("UDP target port:", PORT)

            filename = input("filename?")
            if filename != 'q':
                s.send(filename.encode())
                data = s.recv(1024)
                if data[:6] == 'EXISTS':
                    filesize = long(data[6:])
                    message = input("file exists, " + str(filesize)+ "Bytes, dowbkoad? (y/n)")
                    if message == 'y':
                                    s.send('ÓK')
                                    f = open('new' + filename, 'wb')
                                    data = s.recv(1024)
                                    totalrecv = len(data)
                                    f.write(data)

                                    while totalrecv < filesize:
                                        data = s.recv(1024)
                                        totalrecv += len(data)
                                        f.write(data)
                                        print ("done")
                                        print ("download complete")
                else:
                                print ("file does not exist")
            s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

**Traceback is as follows**

```
exists
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Saqib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32 \lib\threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Saqib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Saqib/Desktop/proj/server.py", line 9, in retrvfile
    sock.send("EXISTS".encode())
OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
```

Comment: s.connect, s.send, and s.recv are functions typically used with tcp, not udp.

Comment: But i need to make a udp file transfer protocol what should i use then.. Help

Comment: I don't know python, but I'd assume your send function in the server does not know who to send to. Typically you would call recvfrom and that would obtain an address that you can then pass to the sendto function.